# Can't commit files to Bitbucket

Tags: xcode, git

I am not able to commit files to bitbucket. it shows error mentioned in screenshot

[image]

Comment: so which is it, bitbucket or github?

Comment: probably you missed git add.

Comment: show us how you are tyring ot commit

Comment: Fonix this is bitbucket error

Comment: @yogesh Try git fetch so that your local repository gets all the new info from github. It just takes the information about new branches and no actual code. After that the git checkout should work fine.